# jQuery Ajax/Jetty; Chrome javascript console showing 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier' from server response

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jetty

I'm trying to make a jQuery mobile app read data from a server I'm running on another computer. When I load the page, I get my 'There was an error loading the data.' message rather than 'Hello World' in my

element. And in the JavaScript console in Chrome, I'm being told that there's 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier' in my server's 'Hello World' response.

I'm stuck, any suggestions? Code for my js and for my Jetty server pasted below:

Here's my Javscript/jQuery:

```
<script>

$.ajax({
    url: 'redacted-my computer's ip',
    dataType: 'jsonp',

    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data, status){
        $("p").html(data);
        }
    ,
    error: function(){
        $("p").html('There was an error loading the data.');
    }
});


</script>
```

And here's my Java code:

```
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet{
private String greeting="Hello World";
public HelloServlet(){}
public HelloServlet(String greeting)
{
    this.greeting=greeting;
}
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    response.getWriter().println(greeting);

}
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Server server = new Server(8082);
    HelloServlet helloServ = new HelloServlet();

    ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
    context.setContextPath("/");
    server.setHandler(context);

    context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(helloServ), "/*");


    try {
        server.start();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(HelloServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    try {
        server.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(HelloServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Hello World" is not in jsonp format, which may be what is causing the error.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I've tried setting the response in response.setContentType to json, jsonp, javascript, html, and plain text, and they've all produced the same result unfortunately.

Comment: I think the error callback takes parameters. You could use them to dump the specific error. Or remove the error callback altogether and see if the error shows up in the debugger.

Comment: Thanks, I took out the error callback, but I'm still getting the 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier'

Comment: What's odd is that though the console is giving me the error at localhost:1, the network tab in the javascript console says that my get received a status of 200 OK as seen in this screenshot: [IMG]http://i42.tinypic.com/iohr29.jpg[/IMG]. I have no idea what the problem is...

Comment: Just noticed: you set response.contentType() to different types. I was actually referring to the line "dataType: 'jsonp'" under .ajax(). Try removing it.

Comment: Wow, thanks! That eliminates the 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier'. Unfortunately, I still can't get 'Hello World' to write to my <p></p>. Do you know why that may be?

Comment: What does it actually do? Does the success function get called at all? Step through it using a debugger, or put "alert(data)" in the success function.

Comment: Nope, success function never gets called, even when I try "alert(data)". I put my error function back in though, and that does get called.

Comment: Small update: I added a 'complete' function, and within it I call 'alert(data)". That result of that function being called is '[object Object]' in the alert pop-up.

Comment: Well, I decided to try the Firefox JS debugger, and in doing so, found that success is called and "alert(data)" actually returns "Hello World"! I'm not sure why it doesn't work correctly in Chrome, but hey big progress.

Answer (score 0):

Learned that to actually get the 'Hello World' message to show up correctly cross-browser that I needed to access data.ResponseText in my complete function